# Identity for the associator involving a third root of unity

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, operads, non-associative-algebras

This is a reference request. I came across the class of nonassociative algebras satisfying the following identity:
$$
(a,b,c)+\omega(b,c,a)+\omega^2(c,a,b)=0.
 $$
Here:

- by an "algebra" I mean a vector space $V$ equipped with a binary operation $V\otimes V\to V$,

  $(a,b,c)$ denotes the associator $(ab)c-a(bc)$,

  $\omega$ denotes a primitive third root of unity (which is assumed to exist in the ground field).

I would like to know if *precisely* this class of algebras was studied in the literature. When I write "precisely", I mean that I do not want classes of algebras where stronger identities hold. (For instance, algebras satisfying this identity *and* the third power associativity identity $(xx)x=x(xx)$ were studied in a [paper of Kleinfeld called 
"Associator dependent rings"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01650067).) The reason to insist on absence of extra identities is that I am especially interested in free algebras of this class (or even in the operad describing algebras of this class), although any extra information would help.

Comment: Note that if you call this $\omega$-something, then if $A$ is an $\omega$-something algebra then $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ is $\omega^2$-something. This can justify to keep track of $\omega$ in the terminology (also if Galois conjugation comes into play).

Comment: @YCor first I want to determine if this class deserves to be named ;)

Comment: @YCor : this new preprint partially reveals my motivation for the question (though this identity ended up hidden in the parametric family of identities discussed there): https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.11142